# Significance of 3D metric tensor $\gamma_{\alpha\beta}$ obtained from 4D metric tensor $g_{\alpha\beta}$ (Landau & Lifshitz)

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

In [The Classical Theory of Fields, Landau & Lifshitz (4th edition)](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=X18PF4oKyrUC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), the authors define a three-dimensional metric tensor in $\S 84$ as follows:
$$\gamma_{\alpha\beta}=\left(-g_{\alpha\beta}+\frac{g_{0\alpha}g_{0\beta}}{g_{00}}\right). \qquad\qquad (84.7)$$
The authors mention that this give the connection between the metric of real space and the metric of four-dimensional space-time.

Using this metric, the authors derive the equation of the force acting on a particle in a constant gravitational field (Problem 1, after $\S 88$) in the usual three-dimensional notation:
$$\textbf{f}=\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}\left[-\nabla \ln\sqrt{h} + \sqrt{h}\frac{\mathbf{v}}{c}\times(\mathbf{\nabla\times g})\right]$$

For low velocities, the second term is analogous to the Coriolis force and the first term is the force due to the gravitational potential.

Question:
I am confused whether this force equation is written in the frame of observers-at-infinity, i.e., the inertial observer frame fixed to distant stars. Or, is the equation valid for comoving observers?

Comment: No, it is the metric an a 3D rest space of an observer  when the space is not 4D orthogonal to the worldlines of the observer . It is the case in particular when you want to define the metric on the rest space of a rotating platform. The vector g is related with the angular velocity there. In that case (if the vector g dies not vanish) it is not possible to synchronise the clocks at rest with the platform with Einstein's prescription and this is equivalent to say that the metric on the platform is not the one induced by the spacetime metric. It is in fact the one presented by L & L.

Comment: That 3D metric $\gamma$ arises by the assumption that the velocity of light measured in a closed path (only one clock) is c. It can be fruitfully used in studying the Sagnac effect. I think it is also known as Born's metric (at least for the rotating platform).

Comment: The 3D metric is just the metric of a 3D manifold embedded in the 4D spacetime that is naturally induced by the 4D metric. You take the 4D $g$ and apply the same rule of the coordinate change, but this time the coordinate change is not from 4D to 4D but from 4D to 3D (i.e. it's an embedding): see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_metric or the "induced metric" section here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor